# How can I store a 3d map allowing O(1) random access? (C++)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently making a C++ client/bot for Minecraft, and I'm wondering if there's a way I could store the world's map using a data structure that allows efficient random access, using either STL or Qt libraries.

The world is always 256 high, but can be infinitely big on the x and z coordinates. It is sent to be in packets containing chunks of 16x256x16 blocks.
Right now I'm storing the blocks in the 16x256x16 sections into arrays, since the size never change, and I store these sections into a stl map using the x and z in a pair as the key.

The problem is that I'm currently working on the AI and I need to access the map a lot, so I'm wondering if there's a better I could store it to improve the access efficiency. I don't care about the efficiency of adding or removing elements. It doesn't need to be sorted either.

Comment: Surely the Minecraft API gives you access to the world geometry (I don't know if that's the case)? So why do you need to store your own copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be using an STL `std::unordered_map`, that'll give you O(1)

Comment: Should be noted that that is the *average* case. Worst case is O(N).

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. I think it doesn't work with pair of ints though, I'll need to find a way to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

If you go the Qt way, you could use `QHash` as an alternative to `std::unordered_map`, with a slightly more convenient API. Also, `QMultiHash` if it is possible to have more than one object at a given coord.

You could `QHasht<Coord3d, Data>` and write a `uint qHash(Coord3d)` function, needed for `QHash`:

```
struct Coord3d {
  uint x, y, z;
};

uint qHash(Coord3d & c) {
  uint h = 0;
  uchar * p = (uchar*)&c;
  for (uint i = 0; i < sizeof(Coord3d); ++i)
    h = 31 * h + p[i];
  return h;
}
```

Also, if you have to traverse through adjacent blocks, it may be worth the extra memory to keep pointers to all adjacent blocks so you don't have to look them up. You could implement your own lookup using each block's adjacent blocks pointers easily. It might be more beneficial to the AI than a hashmap, and will be quicker with typical tasks like path finding.

Comment: To give you an update, I've converted my map to a QHash and the time for my pathfinding algorithm to find the same testing path went from 630ms to 6ms. Thanks!

Comment: That's good, it is low enough to keep it in the main thread instead of using another to keep the gui from freezing.